# I'm trying to use the undetected chromedriver and am continually getting this error

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium-chromedriver

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\Adam\Documents\untitled1\csgoskins.py", line 15, in <module>
    driver = uc.Chrome()
  File "C:\Users\Adam\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\undetected_chromedriver\__init__.py", line 398, in __init__
    if headless or options.headless:
AttributeError: 'ChromeOptions' object has no attribute 'headless'
```

I remember when I was doing something similar about a year ago I got similar errors but I do not remember how I fixed them and cannot find the

My Code:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':  
    import time

    from selenium import webdriver
    from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
    from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
    from undetected_chromedriver import Chrome, ChromeOptions
    import undetected_chromedriver as uc

    options = ChromeOptions()
    options.add_argument('--headless') 

    driver = uc.Chrome()
    driver.get('https:/google.com')
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this problem is due to the change in selenium `4.13.0`

This link says

> "* remove deprecated headless methods"

https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/blob/9a6947ea4fd685b5f997415565bc5dc875a71321/py/CHANGES#L6

Please go through this link for complete discussion and workarounds:

https://github.com/ultrafunkamsterdam/undetected-chromedriver/issues/1584

*it will also work if we downgrade the Selenium version to `4.12.0`*

---

Another way is:

```
options = uc.ChromeOptions()
options.headless = False
driver = uc.Chrome(options=options,version_main=116)

driver.get("https://google.com")
```